# Can't check strings.HasSuffix on string captured with reader.ReadString

Tags: string, go

Overview: I was capturing strings with fmt.Scanln, but one of my needs is that the string must have spaces so I started to use reader.ReadString, I have to check the presence of a suffix in that string to make some replacing, so I used strings.HasSuffix. With strings captured with fmt.Scanln there was no problema but now that I use reader.ReadString it is unabled to find the given suffix in the string.

Is there a clue on what's going on?

Here is a test that isolate the problem, use it in desktop installed Go, not online.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "os"
    "reflect"
)
const TOKEN string = ":="

func validate(expr string) {
    fmt.Println("var type: ", reflect.TypeOf(expr))
    if strings.Contains(expr, TOKEN) {
        fmt.Println(expr, "contains works")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("error with contains")
    }

    if strings.HasSuffix(expr, TOKEN) {
        fmt.Println(expr, "suffix works")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("error with suffix")
    }
}

func main() {
    var expr2 string
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("type something finished with ':='")
    expr1, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Scanln(&expr2)

    fmt.Println("validation with reader: ")
    validate(expr1)
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println("validation with Scanln: ")
    validate(expr2)
}
```

Comment: ["ReadString reads until the first occurrence of delim in the input, returning a string containing the data up to and including the delimiter"](https://godoc.org/bufio#Reader.ReadString)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Tim mentioned the output of `reader.ReadString('\n')` includes '\n' as the last character and `fmt.Scanln` does not do that. You can either do `const TOKEN string = ":=\n"` or remove the '\n' from the end of the string.

Update :

There are cases where `\r\n` occurs as a suffix instead of the usually expected`\n` (Windows Machines ?)

`fmt.Scanln` handles that case as well, as per `fmt` godoc.

`In all the scanning functions, a carriage return followed immediately by a newline is treated as a plain newline (\r\n means the same as \n).`

Comment: @Juanpa works for me, as it should. You must be overlooking something.

Comment: I expected that any string could be treated as the same, being indifferent the way it was caught.

Comment: I had to remove a "\r\n" from the string caught with reader, so it wasn't as simple as just a "\n".

Comment: @Juanpa Are you working on Windows or OSX ? I can confirm that the only `\n` appears when you input the lines in Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm Windows user @JohnSPerayil, when I printed the bytes of each char I've found that there was a byte 13 and a byte 10 after the last char of my string,then looked for http://www.asciitable.com/ to see that 13 is a carriage return, also known as '\r' and then found a new line or '\n'